# how do I insert values while using Hash.Lib while using while loop?

Tags: arrays, loops, lua, roblox

I have the following code... How would I be able to insert values in the array list with different indexes while its looping inside of a while loop? from the 2nd function(HashMine(CarID1))

```
    local function HistoryHash() -- This function is to print out the Hashes "Mined" using Hash.Lib
    for Hashindex = 1, #HashHistory do
        print("Hash "..Hashindex..":", HashHistory[Hashindex])
    end
end
--Mines the BTC pending transaction
local function HashMine(CarID1) 
    while stringtohash:sub(1,2) ~= "00" do
        STRINGTOHASH = stringtohash..HASHNUMBER
        stringtohash = HASHLIBRARY.sha256(STRINGTOHASH)
        HASHNUMBER = HASHNUMBER + 1
        wait(1)
        table.insert()
    end
    
    HashGUI.Text = stringtohash
    PendingTextGui.Text = ""
    local CarID1 = CarBought

    if CarID1 == 1 then
        ConfirmedText.Text = ("Car1 ".. game.Workspace.Cars.Car1Buy.Car1.Value .. "BTC To Malta Car Dealer from " .. Players:GetChildren()[1].Name)
        AfterCarPurchase()
    elseif CarID1 == 2 then
        ConfirmedText.Text = ("Car2 ".. game.Workspace.Cars.Car2Buy.Car2.Value.. "BTC To Malta Car Dealer from " .. Players:GetChildren()[1].Name)
        AfterCarPurchase()
    elseif CarID1 == 3 then
        ConfirmedText.Text = ("Car3 ".. game.Workspace.Cars.Car3Buy.Car3.Value .. "BTC To Malta Car Dealer from " .. Players:GetChildren()[1].Name)
    end
    AfterCarPurchase()
end
```

Comment: adding values to tables is very basic Lua, you should read the Lua manual befor you continue to do anything more complex than simple assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table.insert()` will cause the error message

> bad argument #1 to 'insert' (table expected, got no value)

According to the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual - table.insert](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.insert), it is mandatory to provide the table you want to insert to and the value you want to to insert into that table.

> **table.insert (list, [pos,] value)**
>
> Inserts element value at position pos in list, shifting up the
> elements list[pos], list[pos+1], ···, list[#list]. The default value
> for pos is #list+1, so that a call table.insert(t,x) inserts x at the
> end of the list t.

If you want to assign a value to a specific table index you need to use indexing assignmet `t[key] = value`